# JAVA : How get to the List<String>

Tags: java, string, list

I create class Book with few values.

```
private int id;
private String title;
private String autorName;
private String autorSurname;
private int date;
private List<String> typeBook = Arrays.asList("autobiography", "classic", "comedy", "cookbook",
            "crime story", "drama", "encyclopedia", "fantasty", "novel");
```

create a class constructor

```
public Book(int id, String t, String aName, String aSurname, int d, List<String> tBook)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.title = t;
    this.autorName = aName;
    this.autorSurname = aSurname;
    this.date = d;
    this.typeBook = tBook;
}
```

I want in Main create Object Book

```
Book b = new Book(1, "test", "xxx", "yyy", 2018, tBook);
```

And I have a question. How to get to the list,then choose the type of book ??

Comment: Read about Java getter/setter ...

Comment: To clarify - the list you're defining in your first snippet ("autobiography", "classic", etc), is it that you want that to be the list of all possible book types, then when you create a new `Book` you want to select one (or more?) of those types as that book's type?

Comment: maybe you misunderstood the List<?> , I think you should use `enums`, what I understand is,you want only a set of values to be accepted as the bookType?

Comment: Not sure if the final question is phrased correctly... kind of hints at `MultiValueMap`  or `Map<BookType, List<Book>>`

Comment: When I create Book, I want set one type book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are using the wrong structure for `typeBook`. A book can't be both an encyclopedia and a novel. It's just one type, selected from a set of choices. What you need is an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
enum BookType { ENCYCLOPEDIA, NOVEL, AUTOBIOGRAPHY, etc... };

class Book {
    ...
    private BookType bookType;

    public Book(int id, String t, String aName, String aSurname, int d, BookType bookType) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Following DaveyDaveDave's and Jack Flump's helpful comments, you might want to put a book into a number of categories. For that, you can store an [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) in the Book class:

```
class Book {
    ...
    private EnumSet<BookType> bookTypes;
    ...
}
```

And to make it easy to use, you can make the constructor take a [variable argument list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
    public Book(int id, String t, String aName, String aSurname, int d, BookType... bookTypes) {
        ...
        this.bookTypes = EnumSet.of(bookTypes);
    }
```

And call it like this:

```
    Book tlotr = new Book(
        12345,
        "The Lord of the Rings",
        "J.R.R.", "Tolkien",
        1954,
        BookType.CLASSIC, BookType.FANTASY, BookType.NOVEL);
```

If you want to avoid typing `BookType.` many times, you can add a static import statement at the top of your file:

```
import static my_package.BookType.*;
```

Then you can refer to the enum constants just by name. This only works if your source is in a named package. Also, if the enum is inside a class (such as book) then `import static mypackage.Book.BookType.*;`

Comment: Assuming this is a project for learning the language, if you wanted to go further and really impress your tutor, you could enhance the enum to include some representation of which book types can be combined - for example maybe it's valid to have `NOVEL` and `FANTASY`, but probably not `ENCYCLOPEDIA` and `COMEDY`, then provide a method to validate the combinations. That's probably not required though!

Comment: @DodgyCodeException 
i done it and still I have error in Main : "NOVEL cannot be resolved to a variable"

public class Book {
 
 enum BookType {AUTOBIOGRAPHY, CLASSIC, COMEDY, COOKBOOK,
  CRIME, DRAMA, ENCYCLOPEDIA, FANTASY, NOVEL};
      ...
 private EnumSet<BookType> typeBook;
   

 public Book(int id, String t, String aName, String aSurname, int d, BookType tBook)
 {

  this.typeBook = EnumSet.of(tBook);
 }
}

MAIN :

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Book b = new Book(111, "The Lord of the Rings", "J.R.R.", "Tolkien", 1954, NOVEL, );
  
 }

}

Comment: @student_it Use `BookType.NOVEL` inside the call to `new Book`, or at the top `import static BookType.NOVEL;`

Comment: @student_it see my revised answer

Answer (score 1):

I would look at DodgyCodeException's answer setting up a BookType enum. I'm also going to make the assumption that you're trying to get a List of Books by Type, since it's not entirely clear what you mean by the question.

If you're trying to get a List of Books, you're going to want to implement a MultiValueMap. Just for the sake of example:

```
Map<BookType, List<Book>> books = new HashMap<>();
books.computeIfAbsent(BookType.ENCYCLOPEDIA, () -> new ArrayList<Book>()).add(new Book(...));
```

Once you populate this datastructure. You can get all the books of a certain type.

```
List<Book> encyclopedias = books.get(BookType.ENCYCLOPEDIA);
```

Comment: Good idea, just one minor snag: I don't think `getOrDefault` puts the default value into the map if it doesn't exist. That's what `computeIfAbsent` is for.

Comment: Doh! Great catch. Probably shouldn't be touching production code at this hour... Updated answer

Comment: `computeIfAbsent` takes a Function as argument, so call `computeIfAbsent(BookType.ENCYCLOPEDIA, key -> new ArrayList<Book>())`.

Answer (score -1):

Create getter for typeBook: `List<String> getTypeBook() {return typeBook;}`. Then use it: `...book.getTypeBook().get(index);`

Answer (score -2):

```
private List<String> typeBook = Arrays.asList("autobiography", "classic", "comedy", "cookbook", "crime story", "drama", "encyclopedia", "fantasty", "novel");
public void setTypeBook(List<String> typeBook){
   this.typeBook = typeBook;
}
public List<String> getTypeBook(){
   return this.typeBook;
}
public Book(int id, String t, String aName, String aSurname, int d, List<String> tBook){
   this.id = id;
   this.title = t;
   this.autorName = aName;
   this.autorSurname = aSurname;
   this.date = d;
   this.typeBook.addAll(tBook);
}
```